# Putting articles and sidebars beside each other using floats

Tags: css, css-float

I know at first you might say that this question had been answered dozens of time;
but I must say it seems none of those work for me.(believe me, I spent several hours)
Basically what I'm trying to do is to put several articles beside several sidebars using floats, so I floated the articles to the left and the sidebars to the right, but the page gets messed up, sidebars go underneath the articles and THEN float to the other side.
I'm not sure what I did wrong. I appreciate it if someone could help me find the problem.
Here is the Jsfiddle: [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/BehzadH/f21mL4g6/)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: serif;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #e6e6e5;
}

.mainheader {
  height: auto;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.navbarul {
  background-color: #666664;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 425px;
  box-shadow: 0px 7px 10px #888;
}

.navbarul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.navbarul li:hover {
  background-color: #DF6438;
}

.navbarul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: white;
}

.contentarticle {
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 60%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 7px;
  float: left;
}

.sidebars {
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-left: 70%;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 7px;
  float: right;
}

.sidebars p {
  padding: 1em;
}

.sidebars h2:hover {
  color: #DF6438;
}

.articleheading {
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: 550;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}

.articleheading:hover {
  color: #DF6438;
}

.articlefooter {
  color: #A0A09E;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.mainfooter {
  background-color: #666664;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 1em;
}


/*# sourceMappingURL=main.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Mock Up</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/main.css">
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta name="description" content="Muck Up of a Website">
</head>
<body>
<header class="mainheader">
 <nav class="navbar">
  <ul class="navbarul">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li><!--
    --><li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li><!--
    --><li><a href="#">Blog</a></li><!--
    --><li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</header>
 <div>
 <article class="contentarticle">
  <header class="articleheader">
   <h2 class="articleheading">First Article</h2>
  </header>
  <footer class="articlefooter">
   <p>This Was Posted On the 2nd of march 2013 by Christina Vellisa</p>
  </footer>
   <p>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eos ea enim omnis reprimique. Ea quod tantas option cum, cu quis odio amet vim, probo voluptatum qui in. Usu soluta insolens sadipscing ne, cu numquam vivendum eloquentiam pro. Enim repudiare ut pri. Sed nominati gubergren ad.

   Veri veniam meliore et duo. Quo assum vocent democritum ne. Erat porro an duo, no sit nihil graeci, te odio paulo voluptua sea. At nisl soleat sit.
   Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source
   </p>
 </article>


 
 <article class="contentarticle">
   <header class="articleheader">
   <h2 class="articleheading">Second Article</h2>
  </header>
  <footer class="articlefooter">
   <p>This Was Posted On the 4th of july 2012 by Hexor</p>
  </footer>
   <p>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eos ea enim omnis reprimique. Ea quod tantas option cum, cu quis odio amet vim, probo voluptatum qui in. Usu soluta insolens sadipscing ne, cu numquam vivendum eloquentiam pro. Enim repudiare ut pri. Sed nominati gubergren ad.

   Veri veniam meliore et duo. Quo assum vocent democritum ne. Erat porro an duo, no sit nihil graeci, te odio paulo voluptua sea. At nisl soleat sit.
   Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source.
   </p>
 </article>

  <aside class="sidebars">
   <h2>Top Sidebar</h2>
   <p>Discover how to use new techniques to achieve an outstanding, cross-browser HTML5.</p> 
  </aside>

  <aside class="sidebars">
   <h2>Second Sidebar</h2>
   <p>Veri veniam meliore et duo. Quo assum vocent democritum ne. Erat porro an duo, no sit nihil graeci.</p> 
  </aside>

  <aside class="sidebars">
   <h2>Third Sidebar</h2>
   <p>Usu soluta insolens sadipscing ne, cu numquam vivendum eloquentiam pro. Enim repudiare ut pri. Sed nominati gubergren ad.</p> 
  </aside>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
  

  <footer class="mainfooter">
  <p>Copyright &copy 2016 <a href="#">B.Hatami</a></p>

  </footer>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
body {
  font-family: serif;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #e6e6e5;
}
.mainheader {
  height: auto;
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
.navbarul {
  background-color: #666664;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 425px;
  box-shadow: 0px 7px 10px #888;
}
.navbarul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.navbarul li:hover {
  background-color: #DF6438;
}
.navbarul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: white;
}
.contentarticle {
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  margin-top: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 60%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 7px;
  float: left;
}
.sidebars {
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-left: 70%;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 30%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 7px;
}
.sidebars p {
  padding: 1em;
}
.sidebars h2:hover {
  color: #DF6438;
}
.articleheading {
  font-family: arial;
  font-weight: 550;
  color: black;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
.articleheading:hover {
  color: #DF6438;
}
.articlefooter {
  color: #A0A09E;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.mainfooter {
  background-color: #666664;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Mock Up</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/main.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="description" content="Muck Up of a Website">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="mainheader">
    <nav class="navbar">
      <ul class="navbarul">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <div>
    <article class="contentarticle">
      <header class="articleheader">
        <h2 class="articleheading">First Article</h2>
      </header>
      <footer class="articlefooter">
        <p>This Was Posted On the 2nd of march 2013 by Christina Vellisa</p>
      </footer>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eos ea enim omnis reprimique. Ea quod tantas option cum, cu quis odio amet vim, probo voluptatum qui in. Usu soluta insolens sadipscing ne, cu numquam vivendum eloquentiam pro. Enim repudiare ut pri. Sed nominati gubergren
        ad. Veri veniam meliore et duo. Quo assum vocent democritum ne. Erat porro an duo, no sit nihil graeci, te odio paulo voluptua sea. At nisl soleat sit. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece
        of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going
        through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source
      </p>
    </article>
    <article class="contentarticle">
      <header class="articleheader">
        <h2 class="articleheading">Second Article</h2>
      </header>
      <footer class="articlefooter">
        <p>This Was Posted On the 4th of july 2012 by Hexor</p>
      </footer>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eos ea enim omnis reprimique. Ea quod tantas option cum, cu quis odio amet vim, probo voluptatum qui in. Usu soluta insolens sadipscing ne, cu numquam vivendum eloquentiam pro. Enim repudiare ut pri. Sed nominati gubergren
        ad. Veri veniam meliore et duo. Quo assum vocent democritum ne. Erat porro an duo, no sit nihil graeci, te odio paulo voluptua sea. At nisl soleat sit. Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece
        of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going
        through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source.
      </p>
    </article>
    <aside class="sidebars">
      <h2>Top Sidebar</h2>
      <p>Discover how to use new techniques to achieve an outstanding, cross-browser HTML5.</p>
    </aside>
    <aside class="sidebars">
      <h2>Second Sidebar</h2>
      <p>Veri veniam meliore et duo. Quo assum vocent democritum ne. Erat porro an duo, no sit nihil graeci.</p>
    </aside>
    <aside class="sidebars">
      <h2>Third Sidebar</h2>
      <p>Usu soluta insolens sadipscing ne, cu numquam vivendum eloquentiam pro. Enim repudiare ut pri. Sed nominati gubergren ad.</p>
    </aside>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  </div>
  <footer class="mainfooter">
    <p>Copyright &copy 2016 <a href="#">B.Hatami</a>
    </p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```